# sdl c++ keyboard input using bitmap

Tags: c++, sdl

I have to make a program that allows me to write and all letters that i will press in keyboard will make possible to get a fragment from bitmap image which responds to the letter that I have pressed.I can not use SDL_ttf only SDL_image with c++.

Comment: Your question is too generic - what portion of this do you have a problem with? There are multiple ways of handling input (console, windows messages, etc.) Please be more specific about what you are using and what the requirements are

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a nice bitmap full of ASCII glyphs, like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTEpc.png).
2. Load into a SDL_Surface using SDL_image.
3. In your keyboard handling loop grab the ASCII value when a key is hit.
4. Use the ASCII value to find the correct 8x8 block in the bitmap to copy from.
5. Use SDL_Blit with the appropriate src rect (from step 4) and dst x/y to blit to the screen
6. Increment your dst x value by 8.  Wrap if it gets "too large" and then increment your dst y by 8.
7. **BAM!** Cheesy graphical text input.  Bonus points for handling backspace and/or carriage return.